# Invalid receiver type []T ([]T is an unnamed type) workaround?

Tags: go

I would like to define a method on `[]T`, where `T` is a type I defined.
It looks like i have to define a new type to do this, but that stops me from using all the builtin functions for slices on this new type (such as `len`).

Is the go way of doing this to just make ordinary functions, rather than methods? (Kinda like how `append()` could be a method, but isn't?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can define a slice type:

```
type MySliceType []SomeType
```

- You can still use append and slicing operations on values of `MySliceType`.
- You can define methods on `MySliceType`.

You can't, however, monkeypatch `[]SomeType`'s methods.

Comment: sorry my ignorance, what is monekypatch? it is somehow related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326675/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-define-common-behaviour-for-collection-of-slices?

Comment: Monkeypatching in this context means to change an externally defined type's methods.

Comment: don't get the idea sorry... consider leaving an example if you can. Change an externally defined type's methods would be to redefine a method "m" inside a struct (s) embebbing a another struct (ss) that comes with an original method "m"? Don't see how you could redefine the slices-based methods... that the slices has any type's methods? (for type methods i understand that they are the funcs with pointer or non-pointer reciever)